# Playscape publishing kir (1.17) error: Failed to execture lib2dex

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, playscape

We have problem with PlayscapeSDK 1.17.411 in our Unity Android project.
When we build the game, on "Publishing kit post-process" step we have this error:

*An error occured while applying post-build logic: Failed to execture lib2dex. Error description: jar2dex.*
 [image]

PlayscapeSDK we add in project according to official instruction.
We build project on OS Windows7 x64.
System variables ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME added.
Also path to JAVA exist in PATH variable.

Google Play Service lib(google-play-services.jar) we stripped (3,79 MB)

Using soft:

Playscape sdk 1.17.411

Unity 5.3.2f1

JDK jdk1.8.0_71

By the way, the same error we have, when try to build app on MacOS (El Capitan)